# Need help for a economy game logic

Tags: math, statistics, currency, game-development, economics

### Problem Context

- There is an entity called `Gang`
- Each Gang can have multiple `Members`
- But each member can only join only one Gang.
- Each member has `Coins` as currency
- Each member can deposit coins in Gang.
- Gangs have an `interest rate`. So every week(7 days) Gangs' value increases.

Suppose `Mr. A` invested `50 coins` and `Mr. B` also invested `50 coins`.
So now the gang's total value is `100 coins`.
After two weeks the Gang value becomes `200 coins`.
Now if `Mr. A` wants to withdraw coins he can only withdraw `100 coins` at max because he had a `50%` share of the investment.

#### My question is, How can I determine which member can withdraw how many coins based on their investment?

**Now, the above example is basic and simple. How can I make a formula for a bigger gang, like 10 members? where anyone can withdraw or deposit coins at any moment?**

Comment: Are you using a specific programming language?

Comment: Yes, python 3.9

Comment: You answered the question yourself: *"...he had a 50% share of the investment."* First the gang has 0c. Then A invests 50c, so the gang has 50c and A has 100%. Then B invests 50c, so the gang has 100c, A has 50% and B has 50%. Then the gang's coffer grows to 200c; A still has 50% and B still has 50%. A has the right to withdraw 50%*200c=100c. C invests 50c; now the gang has 250c, A has 50%*200c/250c=40%, B has 40%, C has 50c/250c=20%.

Answer (score 0):

The Gang's worth doesn't have to be a number. It can be an array, something like this:

```
[
    worth of mr. a: 50
    worth of mr. b: 50
]
```

Each of those can be iterated over and summed up to get the total Gang worth. Whenever the Gang's value needs to be doubled, both `worth of mr. a` and `worth of mr. b` can be doubled.